# Wide rows in Cassandra using CQL - getting weird error

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cql

I'm trying to store comments for a blog in Cassandra and have come up with this schema (got the idea from [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/metric-collection-and-storage-with-cassandra)):

```
create table comments ( slug varchar, ts timestamp, value text, primary key (slug,ts));
```

Using CQL (I'm using node.js with [Helenus](https://github.com/simplereach/helenus) driver) I'm trying to add some data to it, here's what I've got so far:

```
var helenus = require('helenus'),
    pool = new helenus.ConnectionPool({
        hosts: ['localhost:9160'],
        keyspace: 'blogks'
    });

pool.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err.name, err.message);
});



module.exports.addComment = function(slug, comment,callback){
    pool.connect(function(connErr,keyspace){
        if(connErr){
            callback(connErr);
            return;
        }

        var cql = "INSERT INTO comments (slug,ts,value) VALUES (?, ?, ?);";
        pool.cql(cql,[slug,serializeDate(new Date()),serializeJSON(comment)],function(err,results){
            callback(err,results);
        });
    });
}

function serializeDate(date){
    var dateSerializer = new helenus.Marshal('DateType');
    return dateSerializer.serialize(date).toString('hex');
}

function serializeJSON(data){
    var utf8Serializer = new helenus.Marshal('UTF8Type');
    return utf8Serializer.serialize(JSON.stringify(data)).toString("hex");
}
```

The idea being you can pass in a comment json object to this method, and push it to cassandra. I'm calling it like this to test:

```
var comments = require('./comments.js');

comments.addComment("myslug",{id:2,name:"Alex",comment:"Hello!"},function(e,r){
    console.log(e);
    console.log(r);
})
```

but whenever I do (I tried various CQL drivers), I get this cryptic error message:

```
[HelenusInvalidRequestException: unable to coerce 'value' to a  formatted date (long)] name: 'HelenusInvalidRequestException'
```

I tried changing the timestamp to be all different data types, but no luck. The very strange thing is that at first, my primary key was just the slug itself, and then it did work. However, I want to store all comments in one row ordered by timestamp, therefore I had to go with this approach of using two columns for the primary key. Any ideas?

**EDIT** So based on [rs_atl's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14813741/15861) suggestion, here's what I've tried:

This line:

```
dateSerializer.serialize(date).toString('hex')
```

did in fact return garbage (0000013ccfacf5c4), I must have misunderstood how to use the API. So here's what I tried instead:

I tried just `new Date().getTime()` which in JS does in fact return Unix-style epoch, but that didn't work I got the same error. I then tried using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to try and format the string:

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

which seems to be returning the correct format, but again. Same error. Then I tried this:

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm") + "Z"
```

no luck. I then tried this:

```
moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mmZ")
```

which does in fact add the timezone info at the end, but still, no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know for sure that you don't have an endianness problem?

Comment: @rs_atl Hmm... I don't know enough about endianness to answer that question. The best I can do is point you to the line of code in Helenus that encodes dates (from what I can tell it's just getting the unix-style epoch and encoding that as a long). https://github.com/simplereach/helenus/blob/master/lib/marshal/serializers.js#L149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems you are using the wrong CQL version.  You expect to use CQL 3.0.0 but the driver defaults to CQL2.  You need to specify the correct CQL version in the initialization.

```
pool = new helenus.ConnectionPool({
    hosts: ['localhost:9160'],
    keyspace: 'blogks',
    cqlVersion: '3.0.0'
});
```

And also please ensure you are using the latest version (0.6.2 as of now) of Helenus.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what the output of this line is:

`return dateSerializer.serialize(date).toString('hex');`

but this is where your issue is.  It appears that you are not outputting a valid date that Cassandra understands.  A valid date is either:

1. A Unix-style epoch as a long value.
2. A string in one of the following forms:

   yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm
   yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss
   yyyy-mm-dd HH:mmZ
   yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ssZ
   yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm
   yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mmZ
   yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
   yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
   yyyy-mm-dd
   yyyy-mm-ddZ

Check to make sure you are writing one of these valid timestamp types.

Comment: Thanks for the input and trying to help. See my update, I tried your suggestions but still no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

For timestamps, I've always use int in milliseconds to represent time.

Try:

```
Date.now()
```

instead of:

```
serializeDate(new Date())
```